# Allowed memory size exhausted when I use "OR"

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In my database, I want to filter the data by date : I have multiple checkbox for that. When I check `2018-2019` for example, I want to get every information `between '2018-09-01' and '2019-08-31'`. I managed to do that. What I can't figure out how to do is when I check two of the checkbox.

I tried using `OR` by doing something like that :

```
AND (date_conseil BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2019-08-31') 
OR (date_conseil BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2018-08-31');
```

But I only get an error *"Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)"*. I really have no idea why I get this and why my SQL doesn't work.

Can you maybe give me a little help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this, look the `(` `)` and the `OR`, it is inside pharentesis.

```
AND (date_conseil BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2019-08-31' 
OR date_conseil BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2018-08-31');
```

Comment: @ElodieG. Nice! Glad to help.